# A notification when the self-answer (being the only answer) can be accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications, self-answer

Sometimes one finds the answer to a question while asking it or briefly afterwards, and after having posted it there's not much of a reason for others to more or less just repeat the answer. The 48h self-accepting limit makes sense, but one may have forgotten about the question after two days, so a notification à la

> You can now accept your self-answer to `<question title here>`

at least when no other (updvoted) answer is there would be helpful.

Comment: Yes please! It happened to me quite a few times where I posted a Q+A and remembered to accept it only a month or so later, when skimming through my question list.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Precisely. I just happen to leave a tab open for two days for the sole purpose of not forgetting to accept my answer, which is really not what tabs should be used for (I have to many open anyway...)

Comment: ...and yet I forgot to accept the self-answer I referred to...

Answer (score -1):

In general, prod askers to look at the answers and accept one if there are some, particularly upvoted ones.

Comment: The problem with making it general is that sometimes you'll get an answer (maybe upvoted a little) which doesn't actually answer your question. it would be annoying if I got prodded for that. I suppose you could get notified once or twice, but then you get the question of what time scale.